# When is the first recorded instance of the lo-shu square?

Tags: ancient-china, mathematics

The [*lo-shu* square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lo_Shu_Square) (洛書) is a 3×3 grid of numbers, usually written as dots:

[image: lo-shu square]

Legend traces its origin to the legendary [Yu the Great](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yu_the_Great) (大禹) or [Fu-hi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuxi) (伏羲) ~3000 years ago, but I'm interested in historically verifiable sources.

There is apparently a reference to the square in Dai Sheng's Book of Rites (小戴禮記) c. AD 60. Was this the first or are there older mentions?

Comment: You got the wrong Dai there. Also, the earliest mention is in the Book of Documents, which based on the discovery of the Tsinghua slips dates to at least 2400 years ago

Comment: @Semaphore I believe you confused lo-shu with ho-tu; the Book of Documents did mention ho-tu (Testamentary Charge, 4; https://ctext.org/shang-shu/testamentary-charge#n21460), but there was no explicit reference to lo-shu.

Comment: @Semaphore The Dai I mean to refer to is 戴德, who is traditionally credited as author of the 'reduced' Book of Rites. If there's a better way to refer to this work and/or its author, please let me know -- I am ignorant in this area.

Comment: @Charles Dai De 戴德 produced the **大**戴禮記 (Dai Senior's Book of Rites); the **小**戴禮記 (Dai Junior's Book of Rites) you mentioned in the question is by his nephew, Dai Sheng 戴聖

Comment: @mooncatcher The earliest the term "lo shu" can be authenticated to have appeared is during the Han dynasty. However, Han scholars  believed that the so-called "lo-shu" was recorded into the Book of Documents by Yu the Great as the as the Great Plan chapter. You're correct that the Book itself indeed does not actually contain the name "lo shu". 《論衡‧正說》夫聖王起，河出《圖》，洛出《書》。 . . . 禹之時，得《洛書》，《書》從洛水中出，《洪範》九章是也。